# Enable ACL in Yarn application in Apache Twill v0.10.0

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, apache-twill

I'm running a yarn application using Apache Twill (0.10.0) in a HDP 2.5 cluster. I cannot see any container logs when I go to a container webpage:
[image]
I suppose I need to set ACL from inside the application in the ContainerLaunchContext. Does Apache Twill expose some APIs to set the application ACL, to do something like this mentioned [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=YO13CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA223&dq=setapplicationacl&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir4oWvuOPTAhXJqo8KHWIBDhIQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=setapplicationacl&f=false):

```
Map<ApplicationAcessType, String>appAclDefinition = new HashMap<ApplicationAccessType, String>();
appAclDefinition.put(ApplicationAccessType.MODIFY_APP, "*");
appAclDefinition.put(ApplicationAccessType.VIEW_APP, "*");
// amContainer is an instance of ContainerLaunchContext
amContainer.setApplicationACLs(appAclDefinition);
```

Or there exists a workaround so that I can see my container logs?

Comment: I found a class [AbstractYarnProcessLauncher.java](https://github.com/apache/twill/blob/401496a7e6996335c5190fc7563a87d0d9008c7e/twill-yarn/src/main/java/org/apache/twill/internal/yarn/AbstractYarnProcessLauncher.java) which has a launch() function which invokes the setter functions of YarnLaunchContext variable. But I see that it does not invoke the launchContext.setApplicationACLs() function. 

Does that mean I cannot specify Yarn application ACLs from Apache Twill yet ?